# Multiple object sets per type are not supported Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new on learning MVC and I have encountered this error.

> Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'checkAccounts' and 'CheckingAccounts' can both contain instances of type 'MVC_ATM.ViewModels.CheckingAccount'.

I looked at similar questions for this kind of error but couldn't spot it out in my codes!!

DbContext

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
    IDbSet<CheckingAccount> checkAccounts { get; set; }

    IDbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    int SaveChanges();
}
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }

    public IDbSet<CheckingAccount> checkAccounts { get; set; }

    public IDbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MVC_ATM.ViewModels.CheckingAccount> CheckingAccounts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The error quite clearly says you have two properties that can contain the same type of object in your db context. This is not allowed. Why do you have two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two classes with the same name, even if the namespaces are different, in the same context. Keyword here is SAME context. If you had another context, then it will be fine. This is because even though you are using code first approach, EF creates an EDMX file behind the scenes. The rules of EDMX are that you cannot have two tables with the same name in the same EDMX.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not with ASP.NET MVC but with Entity Framework. On your db context you have two db sets of the same type.

```
public IDbSet<CheckingAccount> checkAccounts { get; set; }
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MVC_ATM.ViewModels.CheckingAccount> CheckingAccounts { get; set; }
```

Just remove one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I removed one of them and it works perfectly! But why this has happened?

Comment: I thought You have written ApplicationDbContext by hand, so the answer would be 'because You put it there two times'. But if it was generated by a tool, then unfortunately I don't know :(

Comment: I think I ran an update to the database and this was the main reason!! It had generated the ApplicationDbContext automatically after the update commenced! But thank you again for your answer and I appreciate it :)